# Creating a new column in the pandas dataframe depend on the other columns in the same dataframe but different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to the python.

I met a problem that I need to create a new column in the dataframe depend on the other columns in the same dataframe but different rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":[2011,2014,2012,2013],"Value1":[10,40,20,30],"Value2":[10,100,30,60]})
df

        Year    Value1  Value2  Product
0   2011         10      10         1
1   2014         40      100        1
2   2012         20      30         1
3   2013         30      60         1
4   2011         10      10         2
5   2014         40      100        2
6   2012         20      30         2
7   2013         30      60         2
8   2011         10      10         3
9   2014         40      100        3
10  2012         20      30         3
11  2013         30      60         3
```

And I want to creat a new column base on the this year value and last year,the new column value3 should become the quotient of differences between this and last year's value1 and value2, for example, the value3 for year 2012 row should calculated by (30-10)/(20-10) = 2.

So my expected new dataframe should looks like this:

```
    Year    Value1  Value2  Product Value3
0   2011    10      10       1      NaN
1   2014    40      100      1      4.0
2   2012    20      30       1      2.0
3   2013    30      60       1      3.0
4   2011    10      10       2      NaN
5   2014    40      100      2      4.0
6   2012    20      30       2      2.0
7   2013    30      60       2      3.0
8   2011    10      10       3      NaN
9   2014    40      100      3      4.0
10  2012    20      30       3      2.0
11  2013    30      60       3      3.0
```

Can someone help me?

I tried to use for loop to take every row of dataframe, but I found that hard to get last year data as it is not sorted.

Comment: You said value3 of year 2012 should be 2, but your expected output is 3?

Comment: try DataFrame - apply() function

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I have changed my expected output

Answer (score 4):

First `sort_values` on `Year`, do your calculation using `shift`, and then `sort_index` to retain original order:

```
print (df.sort_values("Year")
         .assign(Value3=(df["Value2"]-df["Value2"].shift())/(df["Value1"]-df["Value1"].shift()))
         .sort_index())

   Year  Value1  Value2  Value3
0  2011      10      10     NaN
1  2014      40     100     4.0
2  2012      20      30     2.0
3  2013      30      60     3.0
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer! I met a new problem that the data set inclue several products which both have several years value. This method do not work anymore, even if I choose to sort the products name first then the year, it still will calcuate the 2011 data line using last product 2014 data. Do you have some idea to solve it?